# IOS Create button to hit a URL without opening in Safari

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have found code to open a link upon pressing a button, but I don't want to open a link, just send a command to a web controller without exiting the app.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"192.168.0.100/outlet?5=ON"]]
```

Is there a way to modify this so I don't actually leave my app, but still send the command to my controller?

Eventually I want it to send the on command, then wait like 20 seconds, then send the off command.

Comment: I think the only way to stay in the app is to call the url in a UIWebView.

Comment: Is this URL an API (command?) or a web page? Use UIWebView or SFSafariViewController for presenting web pages inside the app. Use NSURLSession/NSURLConnection to make API calls.

Comment: what do you mean by sending command to my controller ?